# My loop is timing out and not displaying a result

Tags: c++, loops

I am trying to study while loops and I wrote a code to add all the multiple of a given number under three digits, so if you entered 5 it would add 5,10,15,20,25... ect. And they display to total of those numbers. I think I have the code written pretty well, but like the title mentions it is stuck in a loop and will not display a result.

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double getnum()
{
    double num;
    cout << "What multiples are we adding? ";
    cin >> num;

    return num;
}

double calculate(double num)
{
    double cal;
    while (num < 100) ;
    {
        int cal = num;
        num++;
    }

    return cal;
}

double display(double num, double cal)
{
    cout << "the sum of multiples of " << num << " less than 100 are: "
         << cal << endl;
}

int main()
{

    double num = getnum();
    double cal = calculate(num);

    display(num, cal);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why you have used double everywhere? and  initialize cal only once before the loop and and then cal += num; inside the loop.

Comment: Why do you have a `;` after `while (num < 100)`.  With that said after removing the `;` your calculation seems pointless in `calculate()`

Comment: Explain to a friend or a rubber duck how exactly `calculate(5)` adds multiples of 5.

Answer (score 2):

A `for` loop is much better than a `while` loop in this case. `while` loops are better for "do a thing until a condition is met", whereas `for` is better for "do thing X times".

Your code has some mistakes in it, for example

```
double calculate(double num)
{
    double cal; // <--- you return this
    while (num < 100) ; <---- this ; shouldn't be there and causes the loop to never terminate
    {
        int cal = num; <-- you just assign cal here? 
        num++;
    }

    return cal; <--- you return a variable that is never modified
}
```

Hopefully this snippet gets you going:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    int num = 0;
    std::cout << "What multiples are we adding? ";
    std::cin >> num;

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        if( i % num == 0) // modulus division, no remainder
        {
            std::cout << "Adding " << i << std::endl;
            sum += i;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Sum = " << sum<< std::endl;;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
./a.out
What multiples are we adding? 5
Adding 5
Adding 10
Adding 15
Adding 20
Adding 25
Adding 30
Adding 35
Adding 40
Adding 45
Adding 50
Adding 55
Adding 60
Adding 65
Adding 70
Adding 75
Adding 80
Adding 85
Adding 90
Adding 95
Sum = 950
```

In the future it would help to post more readable code, specifically code with comments!

Comment: @MaxLanghof among a ton of other problems incl. calculate not doing anything! I am hoping just seeing the answer will bring some clarity.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason you stuck in the loop is you should not use `;` after the `while` loop. Even if you removed the `;`, the output of your code will not give you the result that you are expecting. You can use the following code as an alternative to that of provided by @Chris

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double getnum()
{
    double num;
    cout << "What multiples are we adding? ";
    cin >> num;
    return num;
}

double calculate(double num)
{
    double cal = 0;
    int inc = num;
    while (num < 100)
    {
        cal += num;
        num += inc;
    }
    return cal;
}

double display(double num, double cal)
{
    cout << "Sum of multiples of " << num << " less than 100 are: ";
    cout << cal << endl;
}

int main()
{
    double num = getnum();
    double cal = calculate(num);
    display(num, cal);
    return 0;
}
```